# Using CKFinder in an Orchard CMS module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, ckfinder

In trying to integrate the CKsource CKFinder control into Orchards CMS. I've already done this with a plain non orchard project,  but am having difficulty with the orchard CMS project.

When popuing up the The finder control I get the following javascript error:

```
It was not possible to properly load the XML response from the web server.

Raw response from the server: 

<%@ Page Language="c#" Inherits="CKFinder.Connector.Connector" Trace="false"    
AutoEventWireup="false" %><%@ Assembly Name="AAA.CMS"%> <%@ Register       
Src="../../../config.ascx" TagName="Config" TagPrefix="CKFinder" %> <%-- * CKFinder * 
======== * http://cksource.com/ckfinder * Copyright (C) 2007-2013, CKSource - Frederico 
Knabben. All rights reserved. * * The software, this file and its contents are subject 
to the CKFinder * License. Please read the license.txt file before using, installing, 
copying, * modifying or distribute this file or part of its contents. The contents of 
* this file is part of the Source Code of CKFinder. * * --- * This is the ASP.NET 
connector for CKFinder. * * You must copy the CKFinder.Connector.dll file to your "bin" 
directory or * make a    reference to it in your Visual Studio project. --%>
```

I've verified my Config.ascx is correct.  I'm able to access the js file.  Is it even possible to integrate ckfinder into a Orchard Module?

Comment: Looks like that thing is a WebForms user control. Good luck with that. Orchard is MVC, and locks down everything webforms. It won't work easily if at all. I would recommend rewriting, at least partly.